# Rails ActionMailer - Attaching text file causes email body to be sent as attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

When I try to attach a text file (with `.txt` extension) to an email, the email is sent with no body and with an additional attachment: `noname.html`. This file contains what I expected to get in the email's body. When I change the file's extension to something other than `.txt` and attach it, the problem does not happen.

Investigating the email's mimeparts reveals that the text attachment mimepart comes before the html mimepart, which I want to be the email's body. However, I'm not sure the order of the mimeparts is causing the problem.

My code for creating the email looks like this:

```
render_to_string # Using a template
attachments[name] = File.read...
mail(options)
```

Adding this to the options argument didn't help:

```
content_type: 'multipart/alternative',
parts_order: [ 'text/html', 'text/enriched', 'text/plain' ]
```

What is the cause of this problem? How can I force the html part to be the email's body?

Comment: `content_type: 'multipart/mixed'`. Can you try that ?

Comment: I get an email with one attachment called "noname", that contains "This is a multi-part message in MIME format..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by attaching text files with mime type `text/x-diff`:

```
mime_type = ... # Get mime type, e.g.: Paperclip::ContentTypeDetector.new(attachment_file_name).detect
mime_type = mime_type == 'text/plain' ? 'text/x-diff' : mime_type
attachments[attachment_file_name] = { content: File.read..., mime_type: mime_type }
```

By swapping the mime type `text/plain` with `text/x-diff`, the text file attachment isn't confused for being the body. It is correctly attached to the email and the email body is correctly sent as the body.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4/5 just use

`render_to_string
 mail.attachments[name] = File.read...
 mail(options)`

adding **mail.** to **attachments** solve the problem.